# android cast to custom View : ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout

Tags: android, casting

i get ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout 
i'm trying to catch the fact that view (Lineralayout) has the elements of listview (one of it's children) in it.

customview:

```
public class MasterView extends View {
public boolean done=false;
public MasterView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public MasterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MasterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    done=true;
    super.onFinishInflate();
}

}
```

the way I call it:

```
View master = (View)findViewById(R.id.master);
MasterView master2 = (MasterView)master; //exception
```

the xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/master"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/cnt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.03" >

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I inflate cnt with the list

Comment: R.id.master is of type LinearLayout not of MasterView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The R.id.master element in your xml is not of type MasterView.  Change your xml to something like:

```
<yourpackage.MasterView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/master"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/cnt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.03" >
  </RelativeLayout>
</yourpackage.MasterView>
```

Comment: extending view crashes the app i had to extend form the linearlayout.